# Border color based on background

Tags: html, css, sass, background-color

I frequently take advantage of `darken` and `lighten` in my SASS styles. I'm currently writing a class which will have a border, but will depend on another class for background color. What I want to do is set the border color to a `darken` of the element's background color.

Something like this:

```
.blue { background: #00f; }
.red  { background: #f00; }

.border { border: 2px solid darken(background, 20); }
```

Then the markup would be:

```
<div id="colored-box" class="blue border">
  <p>
    I have a dark blue border!
  </p>
</div>

<div id="colored-box" class="red border">
  <p>
    I have a dark red border!
  </p>
</div>
```

Naturally, if this worked as I have it written here, I wouldn't be posting this as a question on SO :)

So the question is: **Can I base a `border` color on the `background` attribute *dynamically*, and if so, how?**

Answer (score 40, accepted):

While not a SASS solution, you could just use rgba.

```
.border {
  border: 2px solid rgba(0,0,0, 0.25);
}
```

See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rn8DA/) as an example.

Comment: this is the most natural way. +1

Comment: Although I do like taking advantage of SASS mixins, this is by far the most straightforward answer, and makes it much easier to tie into my existing styles than other answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I would use a mixin like this:

```
.darkenBorder(@color) {
    &.border { 
        background: darken(@color, 20);
    }
}
```

That way, you can easily add a darkened border style to any color:

```
.blue { background: #00f; .darkenBorder(#00f); }
.red  { background: #f00; .darkenBorder(#f00); }
```

---

Even simpler (or more DRY at least), using the same idea:

```
.colorStyles(@color) {
    background: @color;
    &.border { 
        background: darken(@color, 20);
    }
}
.blue { .colorStyles(#00f); }
.red  { .colorStyles(#f00); }
```

---

Output:

```
.blue {
  background: #00f;
}
.blue.border {
  background: #000099;
}
.red {
  background: #f00;
}
.red.border {
  background: #990000;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

as already said, i would go for this, but with a safe reset of `background-clip;`:

```
.border { border: 2px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);/* set here opacity to darken 
to lighten , use rgba(255,255,255,0.X) , any other color can be used too*/
background-clip:border-box; /* make sure bg is layed under border */
}
```

**[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Fmaoh/)**

---

see this as a reminder of use of rgba() colors , as hsla() colors

Comment: the use of rgba colors can be used to lighten, darken or add a color easily : http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/wouBe it is basic color layer sprayed hover anything, just a reminder actually :)

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to **darken** border color (currently - no sass).

1. as [@user3341679's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22998599/128761), using `rgba()`.
2. is using filters `birghtness()` with `opacity()`.

```css
.box {
    border: 5px solid rgba(100, 100, 100, 1);
    filter: brightness(.72) opacity(.7);
}
```

Full example: https://jsfiddle.net/3qwo85js/2/

Image preview

[image: Darken border color.]
Darken border using 2 way of css.

[image: Zoom in of darken border color.]
Zoom in of darken border color.